# how can I extract in js object and operation

Tags: javascript, jquery

there is a obejct `nestObject`
I want to do this

```
nestObject['weakness']['modules']['weakness'][item] = {'enabled': true};
nestObject['weakness']['modules']['weakness'][item]['check_list'] = file_leak_list;
```

I try this:

```
var aaa = nestObject['weakness']['modules']['weakness'][item]
aaa = {'enabled': true};
aaa['check_list'] = file_leak_list;
```

but it doesn't work
how can I write this code elegant?

Comment: what's in `nestObject['weakness']['modules']['weakness'][item]`

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi `nestObject['weakness']['modules']['weakness'][item]` is a Object, I want to change to `{'enabled': true}` in first step, and  set `check_list` in second step

Comment: can you provide a plunkr or jsfiddle ??

Comment: No way for us to know why without seeing sample data and knowing what `item` is. Please show all relevant code. Also show expected results

Comment: What is `item` equal to? What do you see: error thrown, not expected result? Which one is expected?

Answer (score 0):

That is JSON maybe?

```
var nestObject = {
    weakness:{
        modules:{
            weakness:{
                item:{enabled:true, check_list:"file_leak_list"}
            }
        }
    }
};

alert(aaa.enabled);
aaa.enabled = false;
alert(aaa.enabled);

alert(aaa.check_list);
aaa.check_list = "some file";
alert(aaa.check_list);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BernardoBJ/kdnsc8fr/

can you provide a jsfiddle ??

Comment: @Bermardo Borunda please look this:  http://jsbin.com/fagulewoli/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: replace aaa = nestObject.weakness.modules.weakness; for aaa = nestObject.weakness.modules.weakness.item; which is exactly what you need?